# Парсер расширение

Tags: html, парсер

Прошу ввести в курс дела. Есть разные библиотеки для парсинга слышал о jquery слышал о simple_html_dom. Можно ли их прицепить к расширению для браузера? Вообще как это должно выглядеть на пальцах, если прицепить можно? Через расширение пытаюсь сделать, потому что на чистом java запросах, через jsoup, меня сайты забанили ,походу, в конечном итоге). С тем как прописывается расширение я вроде бы разобрался.

Comment: Почитав про simple_html_dom , понял, что это php и его нужно запускать через сервер. Скачал Денвер. Настроить его не выходит. При переходе по ссылке http://localhost/Tools/phpMyAdmin вылазит ряд ошибок. Я правильно двигаюсь или можно как то проще все сделать?

Comment: на одном из сайтов по теме написано: " Кидаем этот файл в папку с проектом и в своем скрипте просто подгружаем его." Как его добавить в расширение и где оперировать его командами?